# Is there any way that a polar coordinate function can be shifted inward or outward without changing the derivative where it exists?

Tags: polar-coordinates

### question

Let f(x) be a polar coordinate function defined from 0 to pi

Is there a translation that pulls f outward (like in the sense f(x) + c does) without altering the polar coordinate derivative?

### context (good for understanding my reasons for asking but not actually relevant for answering)

The reason I ask is becuase I am attempting to comstruct a polar coordinate version of a cartesian construct known as a jump series which is a function that when subtracted from a piecewise continuous function, creates a new composed function that is continuous. Part of its requirements is that the derivative changes knowhere.

Therefore, in order to recreate it, I need to know the basic manner in which I can shift a polar coordinate function inward/outward without changing the deivative. Using this, I will be able to develop a formalized sense of precisely what "jump series" would **mean** in polar coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean by a "polar coordinate function"?

Comment: @EricWofsey it is a well defined term. Use google.

Comment: It seems to me that the natural version of a jump series for a function plotted in polar coordinates is the same as for a function in Cartesian coordinates. A function itself isn't polar or Cartesian, the plot we make of it is.

Comment: @JakobHansen that is not true. A jump series is a property relating explicitly to the graph of the function. Therefore, it will be different in polar coordinates. After all, the polar derivative is different.

Comment: what is polar coordinate function?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Then I think I'm misunderstanding what your definition of a jump series is. My understanding: Let $f$ be a piecewise continuous function. Then $g$ is a jump series for $f$ if $g$ is piecewise constant and $f-g$ is continuous. This has no reference to any set of coordinates for plotting.

Comment: @JakobHansen You forget one thing: the derivative may not change. Derivative of f is equal to the derivative of f-g. The polar coordinate derivative is different.

Comment: The derivative of a function is also independent of how it is plotted. I think you're confusing the derivative of a function with the slope of the tangent line to a function. They're not the same thing, even though they coincide when you plot a single variable function in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @JakobHansen http://calculus7.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/calcplrdrvtvs.pdf http://www.letu.edu/people/stevearmstrong/Math1613/Lesson%2010.7.ppt... You were saying?

Comment: Both of those links agree with what I was saying. The derivative of a function is an intrinsic property of that function; the slope of a tangent line in a plot is not. Under a certain equivalence of the coordinate systems $(x,y)$ and $(r,\theta)$, we can write the derivatives with respect to one system in terms of the other, but that is due to the differentiability of the transition maps; you're really differentiating a different function.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think what you're looking for is always possible. Consider the plot of the function $r(\theta) = \theta$ for $0 \leq \theta < 2$ and $r(\theta) = 1-\theta$ for $\theta \geq 2$. What would you expect the continuified function of that to look like? You can try translating one of the segments to be contiguous with the other, but you won't get the polar plot of a single function. The whole point of polar coordinates is that the natural things to do are to rotate and scale,which do not play nicely with slopes in the Cartesian sense.

Comment: The derivative in two dimensions is defined as dy/dx... dr/dt does not even make sense geometrically as far I am aware.

Comment: @JakobHansen sir, you are focusing on arbitrary context rather than actually answering my question. I asked how you may shift a polar coordinate graphed function without changing the derivative.

Comment: So what you want to do is find a transformation $g$ of a single-variable function $f$ such that when $g$ and $f$ are plotted in polar coordinates, the plot of $g$ is a translated version of the plot of $f$, and in addition, the slope of the tangent line to $f$ at $\theta$ is equal to the slope of the tangent line to $g$ at $\theta$?

Comment: @JakobHansen yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see why this is not possible in general. Let $f(\theta) = 1$. The plot of $f$ is the unit circle. It is not possible to transform $f$ so that its plot moves one unit to the right and it is parameterized in the same way by $\theta$. Where does the line $\theta = \pi/4$ intersect the circle of radius 1 centered at $x=1,y=0$? At the point $x=1,y=1$, which in the original parameterization is given by $\theta = \pi/2$. So there's no hope of getting the same parameterization, and therefore no hope of preserving the slope of a tangent line at a given value of $\theta$ after translation.

Now suppose we give up on that particular condition and simply try to find some $g$ whose plot is a translation of the plot of $f$. (Note that as a result, the tangent slopes will be equal at corresponding points.) Well, this is possible if we move the plot one unit to the right like before, but if we try to move it two units to the right, we run into problems again. For instance, there is no intersection of our desired curve with the line $\theta = \pi/2$. So $g$ cannot have $\pi/2$ in its domain. In fact, we must define $g$ on two disjoint sets in $\mathbb R$, one for the upper half of the circle and one for the lower half. But this is getting further and further from what you probably think of as a function, and is not likely to be useful for defining any sort of jump function.